# Custom map in android

Tags: android, dictionary

Is it possible to draw a map in android without using google maps. Please suggest some good example for the same. Any kind of help would be appreciated:)

Comment: [You need like this one?](http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Map quest](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/android-maps-api) and [bing maps](http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks looks like this would be useful to me:) I simply need to use this sdk and use the maps they provide right?All other concepts of MapActivity and stuff would remain the same?

Answer (score 0):

What do you really want to do?
It's always possible but instead of using native android mapview, you could use another view according to your needs and manage you own gesture detector.

Comment: I want to use some external jar and not the default google maps jar in android. Can you suggest some example for this